# mod_cluster and Tomcat load balancing design

Tags: tomcat, load-balancing, httpd, mod-jk

I am fairly new to Load balancing. I am able to setup a load balancer using Apache httpd, mod_jk and tomcat. Now the problem is we would like to have design in the following manner,

```
                [HTTPD]
                  /\
                 /  \
         [HTTPD LB]  [HTTPD LB]
               /      \
              /        \
  [Tomcat Cluster 1]  [Tomcat Cluster 2]
```

HTTPD LB - Apache Httpd with Load Balancer

But mod_jk only supports AJP protocol, so my questions is - Can the above shown model be designed using mod_jk with Apache httpd and Tomcat?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the need to have 2 levels of apache servers?  Why can't you merge your 2 `HTTPD LB` in a single instance?

Comment: 1st `HTTPD` will serve requests using sticky session so that requests will always go to one of `HTTPD LB`. 2 `HTTPD LB` will not use sticky sessions and will balance the load using their clusters.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  Still, why not have a single `HTTPD LB` (with mod_jk) and drop the other `HTTPD LB` and the front `HTTPD`? Why do you have to separate your Tomcat Cluster in 2 parts?  What makes `Tomcat Cluster 1` different from `Tomcat Cluster 2`? How many Tomcat servers do you have in each of your clusters?

Comment: Using this kind of setup session will be replicated on the servers in its own cluster and as session is replicated request can be handled by any of the server which will increase the performance.

Comment: It seems this kind of configuration is not possible using **mod_jk**. Anyways I configured this design using mod_cluster.